# Hosting an application with rails 3.1 and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, shared-hosting, cloud-hosting

I am a newbie to rails and have developed a rails application with Rails 3.1 and Mysql and i wanted to host my app and tried heroku which to my surprise doesnot offer mysql hosting out of the box (although offers it with Amazon RDS). I have mysql specific SQL queries in my rails app that doesn't make pluging in postgres any easier. Looking for suggestions on a free hosting provider to host my app with rails 3.1 and Mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else looking for options. There are add-ons for Heroku. ClearDB and Xeround are a few. I ended up using ClearDb.